# openvas omp tool is not able to parse target option

Tags: vulnerability-scanners

I am trying out the OpenVAS and the omp tool (version 5.0). I can connect to the OpenVAS manager and get the targets and configs but when I try to create a task, I get an error.

```
 $ omp -u test -w fa542f5d-7943-4a3a-800c-b3ec075dc5ea -T
 b493b7a8-7489-11df-a3ec-002264764cea  Localhost

 $ omp -u test -w fa542f5d-7943-4a3a-800c-b3ec075dc5ea -C \
   -c daba56c8-73ec-11df-a475-002264764cea \
   -t b493b7a8-7489-11df-a3ec-002264764cea 
 Error parsing option -t
```

Can anyone please help me to understand this?

PS: I understand that there is a XML construct and it works but passing commandline parameters is usually much more convenient and scriptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `--target` instead of `-t` works.